# Inline WSDL instead of wsdl:import

Tags: java, jax-ws

Currently the WSDL of my `@WebService` annotated class creates an external wsdl that describe the classes. It does this by:

```
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/myapp-web/Service?wsdl=Service.wsdl"
 namespace="http://somenamespace.org/" />
```

The webservice is being built by eclipse/maven and is being run on jboss 7.1.

Is there a way (preferably by an annotation) to make the wsdl generated inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours searching the web I eventually found the answer.

Having the same targetNamespace on both Interface and implementation Class made the WSDL be exported in one file.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://yournamespace.com")
```